# When hosting an azure MVC app, my web.config's appSettings collection is empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

Using MVC 1.0, and Azure July 2009 SDK

I have an MVC application that appears to be working in the azure test framework, except for the fact that my appSettings collection is empty when running there.  (But if I just run the web project on it's own, it's fine.)

Is there something special I need to do to access the web.config from Azure?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds quite odd... I might check that web.config is getting properly copied when you launch under the dev fabric.  Browse to your app directory and look for a .csx directory.  Under there you should find your web app and hopefully the correct web.config.  If not, then the problem is somewhere in packaging.  (Make sure that web.config is marked as "content" or "copy always" in the properties in VS.)

Otherwise I'm happy to take a look at the project if it's something you can share.  My email address is Steve.Marx@microsoft.com.

Comment: I apologize Steve, I'm not sure what the App Directory is.  I checked under my AppData account, and under the Azure directories I could find under program files, and no luck the only .csx I could find was from a sample application I'd built.  For reference, I'm running Win 7 x64 in VS 2008 as an administrator.

If that doesn't help, I'll send you the code to the email you provided.  Thank you for the help Steve.